# Making multiple get requests to a list of URLs in android

Tags: java, android, python

I basically have a list of strings (about 20 to 60 strings) and I want to send one post request (and get the result which will be in json format and append a specific value from response to a new list) with each item in the list. I want to use ThreadPoolExecutor with a specific number of workers.

I tried few things but unfortunately I couldn't do it. I can do one request at a time but that's not efficient and takes a long time.

I have this code in python which achieves exactly what I want to do but unfortunately I couldn't reproduce it in Java.

```py
#This function makes a single request using one string from the list
def getname(id):
        url = "https://api-public-service.battledash.co/fortnite/cosmetics/search/id?q=" + id
    with requests.session() as ss:
        l = ss.get(url).json()
#we return a value from the response

    return(l['readableName'])




def getnamelist(ids):
    result = []
    ids = deque(ids)
#Turning the list into a dict and back to list in order to remove duplicated items
    ids = list(dict.fromkeys(ids))
#max workers is set to 10
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
#running the getname function which sends a single request and return a name from id
        results = executor.map(getname,ids)
#appending all results into a list
    for it in tuple(results):
        result.append(it)

    return(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: As you did not specify the Java version my answer targets Java >= 8.

Assuming you have the following function that is thread-safe: `public SomeHttpResponseType performGetRequest(String url)`:

```
public List<SomeHttpResponseType> performGetRequests(List<String> urls) {
   return urls.stream().parallelStream()
       .map(this::performGetRequest)
       .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

This uses the default ForkJoinPool. If you want to specify your own thread pool try something like this :

```
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = null;

    try {
        forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(parallelism);
        forkJoinPool.submit(() ->
           urls.stream().parallelStream()
           .map(this::performGetRequest)
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ).get()
    } catch(InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (forkJoinPool != null) {
            forkJoinPool.shutdown(); //always remember to shutdown the pool
        }
    }
```

(adapted version of https://www.codementor.io/nitinpuri/controlling-parallelism-of-java-8-collection-streams-umex0qbt1)

Comment: I'm using android studio. I will see if this can work. Thanks a lot.